# Discussion list body field contains junk text when updated from outlook

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer, email, outlook

I have published a custom workflow for a discussion list which will send email notifications to a particular group. In the email contents I show the subject and body of the discussion. Below are the current items fields i used in the mail content to display the Subject & Body of the Discussion in the email.

```
<table width="650" align="left" style="border-style: solid; border-width:thin; border-color:#EBF3FE;">
    <tr>
        <td style="border-style:solid; height:30px; border-width:thin; border-color:#EBF3FE #EBF3FE #FFFFFF #EBF3FE; background-color:#EBF3FE; width:80px; font-size:9pt; color:#777777; font-family:Calibri; font-weight:bold;">Subject</td>
        <td style="border-style:solid; height:30px; border-width: thin; border-color:#EBF3FE; width:160px; color:#666666; font-family:Calibri; font-size:9pt;">[%Current Item:Discussion Subject%]</td>
    </tr>, <tr>
        <td style="border-style:solid; height:30px; border-width:thin; border-color:#EBF3FE #EBF3FE #FFFFFF #EBF3FE; background-color:#EBF3FE; width:80px; font-size:9pt; color:#777777; font-family:Calibri; font-weight:bold;">Body</td>
        <td style="border-style:solid; height:30px; border-width: thin; border-color:#EBF3FE; width:160px; color:#666666; font-family:Calibri; font-size:9pt;">[%Current Item:Body%]</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If i update the discussion directly in the site means its all working perfectly. But if I update any discussion from outlook (Have connected the discussion list with outlook already), the body of the email contains some junk text. Below is the junk text which was coming in the "Body" field in the email:

```
ExternalClass05EBF893193F4A289A586CCF41465D7B p.MsoNormal, .ExternalClass05EBF893193F4A289A586CCF41465D7B li.MsoNormal, .ExternalClass05EBF893193F4A289A586CCF41465D7B div.MsoNormal
{margin:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;font-size:12.0pt;font-family:'Times New Roman','serif';}
.ExternalClass05EBF893193F4A289A586CCF41465D7B p.msochpdefault, .ExternalClass05EBF893193F4A289A586CCF41465D7B li.msochpdefault, .ExternalClass05EBF893193F4A289A586CCF41465D7B div.msochpdefault
{margin-right:0in;margin-left:0in;font-size:12.0pt;font-family:'Times New Roman','serif';}
.ExternalClass05EBF893193F4A289A586CCF41465D7B span.emailstyle17
{;}
.ExternalClass05EBF893193F4A289A586CCF41465D7B span.emailstyle171
{font-family:'Calibri','sans-serif';color:windowtext;}
.ExternalClass05EBF893193F4A289A586CCF41465D7B p.msochpdefault1, .ExternalClass05EBF893193F4A289A586CCF41465D7B li.msochpdefault1, .ExternalClass05EBF893193F4A289A586CCF41465D7B div.msochpdefault1
{margin-right:0in;margin-left:0in;font-size:12.0pt;font-family:'Calibri','sans-serif';}
.ExternalClass05EBF893193F4A289A586CCF41465D7B span.emailstyle172
{font-family:'Calibri','sans-serif';color:windowtext;}
.ExternalClass05EBF893193F4A289A586CCF41465D7B p.msochpdefault2, .ExternalClass05EBF893193F4A289A586CCF41465D7B li.msochpdefault2, .ExternalClass05EBF893193F4A289A586CCF41465D7B div.msochpdefault2
{margin-right:0in;margin-left:0in;font-size:12.0pt;font-family:'Calibri','sans-serif';}
.ExternalClass05EBF893193F4A289A586CCF41465D7B span.emailstyle173
{font-family:'Calibri','sans-serif';color:windowtext;}
.ExternalClass05EBF893193F4A289A586CCF41465D7B p.msochpdefault3, .ExternalClass05EBF893193F4A289A586CCF41465D7B li.msochpdefault3, .ExternalClass05EBF893193F4A289A586CCF41465D7B div.msochpdefault3
{margin-right:0in;margin-left:0in;font-size:12.0pt;font-family:'Calibri','sans-serif';}
.ExternalClass05EBF893193F4A289A586CCF41465D7B span.EmailStyle25
{font-family:'Calibri','sans-serif';color:#1F497D;}
.ExternalClass05EBF893193F4A289A586CCF41465D7B .MsoChpDefault
{font-size:10.0pt;}
@page WordSection1
{size:8.5in 11.0in;margin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;}
.ExternalClass05EBF893193F4A289A586CCF41465D7B div.WordSection1
{page:WordSection1;}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Dhileep,

How important is the formatting for you? 
If not important try copying the text in text notepad and then copy and paste from there. ( I know it's a ugly workaround )
OR
Try setting post format in Outlook to plain text

Alternately,
Try setting post format in outlook to HTML only.

The junk text you posted looks like Word/Rich Text specific formatting information that Sharepoint is not striping out. The Richtext control in Sharepoint does that specifically hence if works if you do a paste in Sharepoint directly.